# Style label of a checked radio button, which is wrapped in label tag

Tags: css, input, radio-button, checked

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction when it comes to the following issue.

So I have this code:

```
<label class="option"><input type="radio" name="rectangle" value="3 1/8 inches" checked><span>d</span> 3 1/8 inches</label>
```

What I want to achieve is to style label.option, which should be based on radio button state checked. What would be the easiest way to achieve using CSS only?

Thanks

Comment: Why is the checkbox inside the label? Are you able to edit the html?

Answer (score 2):

maybe so

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
span{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span{ 
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<label class="option" for="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="rectangle" value="3 1/8 inches" /><span>d 3 1/8 inches</span></label>
```

Comment: Thanks. Pretty close. I figured it out using jQuery.

Comment: This got me on the right track. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the :checked selector.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="rectangle" value="3 1/8 inches" checked>
<label for="rectangle" class="option"><span>d</span> 3 1/8 inches</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
   color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: It only works when label follows input radio. However, I need input wrapped in label. Thanks for your suggestion, but I figured it out using jQuery. :)